# XPages "home made" custom control not recognized

Tags: xpages

I have added the rich text custom control from the book Mastering Xpages 2nd edition to one of my application, but I keep on getting the following:

```
2016-02-19T15:20:30.546-05:00 SEVERE CLFAD0095E: Format error reading the class mxpd2.component.InputRichText   
2016-02-19T15:20:30.547-05:00 WARNING CLFAD0090W: The component-class (mxpd2.component.InputRichText) could not be resolved for the component with component-type com.ibm.xsp.InputRichText.
```

The application used to be able to compile when I did a "clean" on the project, but now I get the error all the time.

Here is my mxpd2.xsp-config file:

```
<faces-config>

<faces-config-extension>
    <namespace-uri>http://www.ibm.com/xsp/mxpd2</namespace-uri>
    <default-prefix>mxpd2</default-prefix>
</faces-config-extension>

<component>
    <description>A specialized Rich Text Editor control for Intact Financial Corp</description>
    <display-name>In‌tact Rich Text</display-name>
    <component-type>com.ibm.xsp.InputRichText</component-type>
    <component-class>mxpd2.component.InputRichText</component-class>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.core.prop.styleClass</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.core.prop.title</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.events.prop.onclick</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.events.onkey</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.focus</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.i18n</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.input.prop.disabled</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.input.prop.onchange</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.input.prop.readonly</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.outerStyleClass</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.filter</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.dojoUsage.deprecated</group-type-ref>
    <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.aria.role</group-type-ref>
    <property>
      <display-name>CSS Style</display-name>
      <property-name>style</property-name>
      <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
      <property-extension>
        <pass-through>true</pass-through>
        <designer-extension>
          <category>styling</category>
          <editor>
            com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.StylesEditor
           </editor>
          <styles-excluded>background, font</styles-excluded>
        </designer-extension>
      </property-extension>
    </property>
    <component-extension>
      <javadoc-description>
        <p>Rich Text Control</p>providing rich text editing functionality
       </javadoc-description>
      <base-component-type>com.ibm.xsp.UIInputRichText</base-component-type>
      <renderer-type>com.ibm.xsp.InputRichText</renderer-type>
      <tag-name>inputRichText</tag-name>
      <designer-extension>
        <category>Intact FC</category>
      </designer-extension>
    </component-extension>
</component>

</faces-config>
```

It is an almost exact copy of the source code from the book's sample file (Chapter 11b).  The java files have been copied into my app(same package), the faces-config.xml shas been modified to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <converter>
    <converter-id>InputRichTextConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>mxpd2.converter.InputRichTextConverter</converter-class>
  </converter>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>rteBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mxpd2.bean.InputRichTextBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>debug</property-name>
      <value>false</value>
    </managed-property>
  </managed-bean>
  <managed-bean id="Appconfig">
    <managed-bean-name>AppConfig</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.intact.xpages.utils.AppConfig</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
  <managed-bean id="SessionConfig">
    <managed-bean-name>SessionConfig</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.intact.xpages.utils.SessionConfig</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>EmailBeanV2</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.intact.xpages.utils.EmailBeanV2</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>debugMode</property-name>
      <value>false</value>
    </managed-property>
  </managed-bean>
  <!-- required for the lang switch 
  <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>ch.hasselba.xpages.jsf.core.LocalizationSetter</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>
  -->
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by IBM Domino Designer. Do not modify.-->
  <application>
    <locale-config>
      <default-locale>fr</default-locale>
      <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
      <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
  </application>
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>
```

I copied everyhting twice to make sure, but still get the error.

In the original file, I don't have any errors in source mode, but when looking in design mode though, I get a warning that the tag mxpd2 is not recognized and the control is yellow instead of blue.

Can somebody pinpoint the issue?

---

Here is what I found in the trace log:

```
09:32:37.429 7 SEVERE com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.ParseUtil
getClassForName CLFAD0095E: Format error reading the class mxpd2.component.InputRichText
java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE113 EOF inattendu; classe=mxpd2/component/InputRichText, décalage=0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.server.util.DynamicClassLoaderVFS.doDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.server.util.DynamicClassLoaderVFS.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.ParseUtil.getClassForName(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.ParseUtil.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.definition.ComponentParser.getJavaClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.definition.ComponentParser.createDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.definition.AbstractDefinitionParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.ConfigParserImpl.createDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.FacesConfigParserImpl.processChildElements(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.FacesConfigParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.ConfigParserImpl.createFacesLibraryFragment(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.ConfigParserImpl.createFacesLibraryFragment(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.config.ConfigRegisterer.register(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.config.ConfigRegisterer.registerProjectConfig(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.registry.config.ConfigRegisterer.registerProjectConfig(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ConfigFileMaintainerImpl.reloadAllConfigFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.project.FacesRegistryMaintainer.changedClassFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources.project.DesignerProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.getAffectedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.notifyChangedOrAddedDesignerProject(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.prj.resources.commons.CommonProjectSynchronizer.resourceChanged(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)


09:32:37.430 7 WARNING com.ibm.xsp.registry.parse.definition.ComponentParser
getJavaClass CLFAD0090W: The component-class (mxpd2.component.InputRichText) could not be resolved for the component with component-type com.ibm.xsp.InputRichText.
```

Answer (score 1):

some things to check:

can you see any relevant errors under help -> support -> show log
help -> support -> show trace
(sorry if not exact I am not at my computer)
some times you will find errors in here related to invalid xsp config

I can't see your Java source for component, but can
you double check the class name under  is exact? if you have renamed the package or class name then it won't find it.

is your namespace (mxpd ) included at the top of your xpages source? if it is not referenced at the top, then it won't know to find the component under that namespace.

also I find that sometimes when developed a uicomponent within an NSF, I have to clean 2 times in a row. designer just gets confused sometimes.

**edit**
from the trace, it looks like your . java file might not be compiled to a .class file properly. when the registry is trying to parse the class file it is getting an unexpected EOF. 
try making a small change to the Java file to trigger another build (add a comment or white space)
make sure there are no compilation errors

Comment: I added the trace log to my question.  The java package for that class is mxpd2.component and the class name is InputRichText.  The namespace is included at the top of the xpages.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I already tried that.  Works but the error comes back the next time designer is opened. :/

Comment: yeah I'm afraid that when you develop UI controls from within the NSF you must resign yourself to encountering these sort of build errors on a frequent basis. it is very annoying and you just have to clear them and move on. if you move to developing UI control from within OSGi plugins you won't encounter this anymore. (but there are other annoyances there too!)